# 'seek' argument in command dd

Tags: dd

Can some explain me what is happening in the following lines?

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 seek=7 count=2 of=file_with_holes
```

especially seek part is not clear

Man pages says :

```
 seek=BLOCKS
              skip BLOCKS obs-sized blocks at start of output
```

What is obs-sized block?

Comment: I dont think seek will change the data its skipping over, so no, i dont think empty zeroed blocks will appear before the block you are seeking to, whatever data was there would remain.

Answer (score 29):

`dd` is designed to copy **blocks** of data from an input file to an output file. The `dd` block size options are as follows, from the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dd.html):

```
ibs=expr
    Specify the input block size, in bytes, by expr (default is 512).
obs=expr
    Specify the output block size, in bytes, by expr (default is 512).
bs=expr
    Set both input and output block sizes to expr bytes, superseding ibs= and obs=.
```

The `dd` `seek` option is similar to the UNIX `lseek()` system call<sup>1</sup>. It moves the read/write pointer within the file. From the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dd.html):

```
seek=n
    Skip n blocks (using the specified output block size) from the beginning of the output file before copying.
```

Ordinary files in UNIX have the convenient property that you do not have to read or write them starting at the beginning; you can seek anywhere and read or write starting from there. So `bs=4096 seek=7` means to move to a position 7*4096 bytes from the beginning of the output file and start writing from there. It won't write to the portion of the file that is between 0 and 7*4096 bytes.

Areas of ordinary files that are never written to at all aren't even allocated by the underlying filesystem. These areas are called **holes** and the files are called **sparse files**. In your example, `file_with_holes` will have a 7*4096-byte hole at the beginning. (h/t @frostschutz for pointing out that `dd` truncates the output file by default.)

It is OK to read these unallocated areas; you get a bunch of zeroes.

[1] back when `dd` was written, the analogous system call was `seek()`.

Comment: Interesting, my man page is annoyingly unforthcoming on this - ` bs=BYTES read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time`

Comment: I haven't seen "seek" on UNIX, Maybe "lseek" I guess.

Comment: @kangear [seek](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man2/seek.2) was the predecessor of `lseek`. I've updated my answer to be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note, I was trying to seek a drive device (exmaple: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=2 seek=8388607998 of=/dev/sdd`), but those 'files'/descriptors are not seekable: `dd: /dev/sdd: cannot seek: Invalid argument 0+0 records in 0+0 records out 0 bytes copied, 0.00765396 s, 0.0 kB/s`

Comment: @Pysis Disk devices are usually seekable, but maybe there are some issues with very large devices.  How large (in bytes) is your /dev/sdd ?

Comment: Maybe I have before and can't remember.  I'm trying to access the backup GPT sector or 2 at the end of a 4TB disk.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers explained it already, but if you have any doubts, you can see what `dd` does with `strace`.

```
$ strace dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 seek=7 count=2 of=file_with_holes
# output is shortened considerably
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 0
open("file_with_holes", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 1
ftruncate(1, 28672)                     = 0
lseek(1, 28672, SEEK_CUR)               = 28672
read(0, "\244\212\222v\25\342\346\226\237\211\23\252\303\360\201\346@\351\6c.HF$Umt\362;E\233\261"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "\244\212\222v\25\342\346\226\237\211\23\252\303\360\201\346@\351\6c.HF$Umt\362;E\233\261"..., 4096) = 4096
read(0, "~\212q\224\256\241\277\344V\204\204h\312\25pw9\34\270WM\267\274~\236\313|{\v\6i\22"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "~\212q\224\256\241\277\344V\204\204h\312\25pw9\34\270WM\267\274~\236\313|{\v\6i\22"..., 4096) = 4096
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
write(2, "2+0 records in\n2+0 records out\n", 312+0 records in
2+0 records out
) = 31
write(2, "8192 bytes (8.2 kB) copied", 268192 bytes (8.2 kB) copied) = 26
write(2, ", 0.00104527 s, 7.8 MB/s\n", 25, 0.00104527 s, 7.8 MB/s
) = 25
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It opens `/dev/urandom` for reading (`if=/dev/urandom`), opens `file_with_holes` for create/write (`of=file_with_holes`).

Then it truncates `file_with_holes` to `4096*7`=`28672` bytes (`bs=4096 seek=7`). The truncate means that file contents after that position are lost. (Add `conv=notrunc` to avoid this step). Then it seeks to `28672` bytes.

Then it reads `4096` bytes (`bs=4096` used as `ibs`) from `/dev/urandom`, writes `4096` bytes (`bs=4096` used as `obs`) to `file_with_holes`, followed by another read and write (`count=2`).

Then it closes `/dev/urandom`, closes `file_with_holes`, and prints that it copied `2*4096` = `8192` bytes. Finally it exits without error (0).

Answer (score 5):

`obs` is the output block size and `ibs` is the input block size. If you specify `bs` without `ibs` or `obs` this is used for both.

So your seek will be 7 blocks of 4096 or 28672 bytes at the start of your output. Then you will copy 2 blocks of 4096 or 8192 bytes from the start of input to this point in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Seek will just "inflate" the output file. Seek=7 means that at the beginning of the output file, 7 "empty" blocks with output block size=obs=4096bytes will be inserted. This is a way to create very big files quickly.

Comment: Or to skip over data at the start which you do not want to alter. Empty blocks only result if the output file initially did not have that much data. The manual is also not clear on how `obs` relates to `bs`, the command uses `bs` which will substitute `obs` if it is not there.